# radGrid Add new record vs. Edit Record

Tags: telerik, radgrid

Does anyone know how to validate if you are in Add Mode vs. Edit Mode for the radGrid?  In the codebehind, I want to check to see if the user selected Add a Record or Edit an Existing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I learned when playing with RadGrid for ASP.NET AJAX is:
- the IsItemInserted property of the master table can help you find out whether you are in insert mode or not
- the when EditItems or EditIndexes collections are not empty, you have grid items in edit state

Dick

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  I did end up using the following:

If TypeOf e.Item Is GridEditFormInsertItem AndAlso e.Item.OwnerTableView.IsItemInserted Then

Thanks for your help.

R